# Can iBeacon tell 1cm from 10 cm?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ibeacon, proximity

so the question is in the headline. I need to find a technology that will tell whether my phone is like 1cm or less from the point A, or its 10cm or more from point A.

Can I determine this using single iBeacon? If so in what mode it should be run?

Thanks!

Comment: I would have to say no, at least not with any sort of efficiency. The estimate is usually calculated based off of a best fit curve using a number of signal strengths and those can be super variable. You may be able to tell closer from further with some success, but exact ranges (especially at that small of a distance) are going to be difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this just isn't going to work with bluetooth beacons.  There are several problems:

1. Each device (iPhone models, Android models) have a slightly different  bluetooth antenna gain.  The signal level and therefore estimated distance will be different for each.  The range of error will be more then 1-10cm.
2. Some mobile device models are more than 10cm long.  One part of the phone (with the antenna) might be 10cm away, and the other part 1cm away.
3. There is always radio noise.  Radio noise will certainly cause distance estimates 1-10cm.
4. Signal reflections and near-field effects will make signal levels unpredictable at such close range.